# Upload with python program into anonymous nextcloud share

Tags: python, nextcloud

The nextcloud manual [describes](https://docs.nextcloud.com/server/latest/user_manual/en/files/file_drop.html) a possibility to create anonymous upload space for users.

If one creates such an upload space, a URL is created and can be shared, allowing multiple users without nexcloud accounts to upload files.

However, these files need to be dragged and dropped into a browser window. In contrast, I want to directly upload them in a python program.
I cannot really use a nextcloud package for this such as described [here](https://github.com/EnterpriseyIntranet/nextcloud-API/blob/master/example.py), since I do not have (and do not want to create) user accounts for every uploader.

Any ideas how to proceed? I could use a package such as selenium to imitate user actions in the browser, but that seems somewhat clumsy.

[EDIT:]

And have used a curl command as described [here](https://doc.owncloud.com/webui/next/classic_ui/files/access_webdav.html#uploading-files-to-a-public-link-file-drop-using-curl) for owncloud, hoping that this would work similarily for nextcloud, and I translated the curl command using [curlconverter](https://curlconverter.com/), but got an error 405.

[EDIT 2:]
I got a little bit further with the following modified code (modified URL), which returns status 200. But I still don't see an uploaded file.

```
headers = {'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest',}

with open('test.txt', 'rb') as f:
    data = f.read()

response = requests.put(
    'https://xxx.xxx.com/remote.php/s/test.txt',
    headers=headers,
    data=data,
    verify=False,
    auth=('94daw3R3sfwrNaeK', ''),
)
```

[EDIT 3:]
It seems that the problem is related to the URL in use. I am rechecking with direct use of CURL.

Comment: You could use a standard file upload into a folder in the file system inside the nextcloud files space. Something like `scp` or `sftp`. Then all that is left would be to trigger the `occ` command to rescan the files for that location by nextcloud. So that the file index is up to date. `rsh` would allow such thing in combination with `sudo`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As expected, a change in URL was necessary. This piece of code did the trick:

```
headers = {'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest',}

with open('test.txt', 'rb') as f:
    data = f.read()

response = requests.put(
    'https://xxx.xxx.com/public.php/webdav/test.txt',
    headers=headers,
    data=data,
    verify=False,
    auth=('94daw3R3sfwrNaeK', ''),
)
```